# Webix - How do I parse JSON from a URL before using it in a data table?

Tags: javascript, json, webix

I'm messing around with Webix and the League of Legends API to see some champion data.  The League API just gives you back giant JSON files that you can use to display data.  However, I'm not sure what the best way to go about parsing these files for use in my data views are.

Here's my webix code for the datatable:

```
var leagueTable = {
  rows: [
    {
      view: "template",
      type: "header", template: "Champion Stats"
    },
    {
      view: "datatable",
      autoConfig: true,
      url: RiotApiUrlUtility.getFindSummonerUrl("someSummoner")
    }
  ]
};
```

The URL works and I get back the JSON I'm expecting. However, the JSON is structured such that the table doesn't display data how I want. (The table is rendered fine and it shows my summoner name from the json in the table, but the relevant data is nested further so the default parsing of the json doesn't know how to put it in the table).

I've looked through the documentation for webix and it might be the case that I have to use a DataProcessor, but the documentation is confusing without any concrete examples. I'm sure this operation must be pretty simple and I'm just missing something. Can anyone assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I did:

```
  webix.ajax().get(RiotApiUrlUtility.getFindSummonerUrl("aSummoner"),{
    error:function(text, data, XmlHttpRequest){
      alert("error");
    },
    success:function(text, data, XmlHttpRequest){
      var data = JSON.parse(text);
      $$('champDataTable').parse(data.aSummoner);
    }
  });
```